# Iterate select attribute and buffer creation

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to retrace my steps from a few months ago.  I'm working on a project where I have 161 points in a shapefile.  I'm hoping there's a python script for selecting each point by the row, exporting it, and creating a 2.5 mile buffer around it.  What I meant by retracing my steps is that I've already done this in python using a script I found in here, but now I can't find it.

Comment: if you just working with the geometry here is the process I would use 1. searchcursor to loop through geometry of each row 2. use the geometry.buffer() method with 2.5 miles 3. use the copy features tool to export that polygon buffer with a unique name

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a modelbuilder solution, the following will accomplish what you are trying to do and may be more simple than writing a script:

[image]

Connect your point layer to the 'Iterate Feature Selection' tool.

'Value' will be the value of the field you have set in the iterator.  If you haven't set a field, the value will be the FID.

By using %Value% in the output, it will name the output with the value of the current selection.  In my example each output would be PointBuffer_1, PointBuffer_2, PointBuffer_3, etc.

Note:  If you want to turn this into a tool, make the input point layer and the output buffer model parameters.  Then save the model in a toolbox.  You can then use it like any other tool and will be able to set the input feature class and output feature class.

Comment: That worked great.  I'm also in the middle of using this frame work where buffer is replaced by extract by mask and the point file is replaced by the buffers created.  Thanks this is great.

Comment: If it has helped you please accept the answer or upvote it to show others that it is useful.  Thanks.  I'm glad I could help you.